# Creating a function in php and using $_POST

Tags: php

`enter code here`I've been having difficulties with using the $_POST and/or $_GET. It won't let me retrieve any of the attributes i insert into my form.

Here are my functions;

```
<?php
function createTextField($label, $name, $size, $defaultValue)
{
    //print our paragraph
    echo '<p>';

    //print our label
    echo "<label>$label: </label>";
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$name.' size="'.$size.'" value="'.$defaultValue.'"';

    echo '</p>';   
}

function createTextArea($label, $name, $cols, $rows, $defaultValue)
{
    //print our paragraph
    echo '<p>';

    //print out label
    echo "<label>$label: </label>";
    echo '<textarea value ="'.$text.'" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>';

    echo '</p>';
}

function createRadioButtons($label, $name, $choice1, $choice2, $choice3)
{
    //print our paragraph
    echo '<p>';

    //print our label
    echo "<label>$label: </label>";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$radio.'" value=value>'.$choice1.'';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$radio.'" value=value>'.$choice2.'';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$radio.'" value=value>'.$choice3.'';
    echo '</p>';
}

function createDropDown($label, $name, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4)
{
    //print our paragraph
    echo '<br>';

    //print our label


    echo "<label>$label: </label>";
    echo '<select name="'.$option.'">
        <option value="option">'.$option1.'</option>
        <option value="option">'.$option2.'</option>
        <option value="option">'.$option3.'</option>
        <option value="option">'.$option4.'</option>
        </select>';

    echo '</p>';

}
```

Then my form;

```
 <form action="questionnaire_results.php" method="post">
<h2>Questionnaire:</h2>
<?php
    // create TextField
    echo '<div style="width:520px;height:175px;border:3px solid black;">';
    createTextField('Name', 'label', 'size', '');
    createTextField('Age', 'label', 'size = 5', '');
    createTextField('Address', 'label', 'size = 30', '1000 1st St. Seattle, Wa 98999');
    createTextField('Address (cont)', 'label', 'size = 10', 'APT 13');

    echo '</div><br>';

    //create TextArea
    echo '<div style="width:520px;height:175px;border:3px solid black;">';
    createTextArea('Short biography', 'label', 'cols', 'rows', 'defaultValue');
    createTextArea('Extra Notes', 'label', 'cols', 'rows', 'defaultValue');
    echo '</div><br>';

    //create RadioButtons
    echo '<div style="width:520px;height:75px;border:3px solid black;">';
    createRadioButtons('Gender', 'name', 'Male', 'Female', 'Other');
    createRadioButtons('Employment', 'name', 'Employed', 'Not Employed', 'Not sure');
    echo '</div><br>';

    //create DropDown 
    echo '<div style="width:520px;height:50px;border:3px solid black;">';
    createDropDown('Did you like this questionnaire?', 'name', 'Yes', 'Sort Of', 'Maybe', 'No');
    echo '</div><br>'; 
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Questionnaire Answers!"> 
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

and finally my results that doesn't seem to work right now:

```
$name = '.name.';
$address = 'address';
$text = 'text';
$notes = 'notes';
$radio = 'radio';
$option = 'option';


if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo "Name: $name<br>";
} else {
  echo 'Name field cannot be empty!<br>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['address'])) {
  $name = $_POST['address'];
  echo "Address: $address<br>";
} else {
  echo 'Address field cannot be empty!<br>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
  $name = $_POST['text'];
  echo "Short Biography: $notes<br>";
} else {
  echo 'Notes field cannot be empty!<br>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['radio'])) {
  $name = $_POST['radio'];
  echo "Gender: $radio<br>";
} else {
  echo '';
}

if (!empty($_POST['option'])) {
  $name = $_POST['option'];
  echo "Employment: $option<br>";
} else {
  echo '';
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see a form element. Do a `print_r` of the `$_POST` data to see what you're receiving.

Comment: You don't have form tag in your code

Answer (score 1):

Your form elements must be enclosed by a [form tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp), else nothing will be posted.

And you should add a button to the form to submit the form data.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Here an example :

```
<?php
    echo '<div style="width:520px;height:175px;border:3px solid black;">';
    echo '<form action="yourScript.php" method="post">';

    // your form fields
    // createTextField(...);
    //createTextArea(...);
    //create RadioButtons
    //create DropDown 
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
    echo '</form>';
```

There are many problems with your code.
You render the text field like this:

```
function createTextField($label, $name, $size, $defaultValue) {
    // ...
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$name.' size="'.$size.'" value="'.$defaultValue.'"';
    // ...
}
```

But you call the function like this which is :

```
    createTextField('Name', 'label', 'size', '');
    createTextField('Age', 'label', 'size = 5', '');
```

Now the variable `$name` will contain the text 'label', `$size` will contain the text 'size' and so on.
This will render the follwing **invalid** html :

```
<input type="text" name="label size="size" value=""
<input type="text" name="label size="size = 5" value=""
```

There are several problems:

- the input tag is not closed
- the name quote is not closed
- the size attribute does not contain a number

The following should be correct, however I didn't test it :

```
function createTextField($label, $name, $size, $defaultValue) {
    // ...
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$name.'" size="'.$size.'" value="'.$defaultValue.'"></input>';
    // ...
}
```

And the you call it like this

```
createTextField('Name', 'name', '5', '');
```

I suggest that you first read some tutorials about php and html.
This [site](http://www.w3schools.com/) might help you, it contains a section with tutorials, but you will find many other resources if you search the web.

Comment: This answer's better, as it specifies both the problem with the original script, and it also uses `method="post"`, which is required for a valid form.

Comment: It continues to only post out "field cannot be empty" even when i try typing in a name for the name field.

Comment: @anonymous4321 I updated my answers, there are many issues with your code.

Comment: Oh i know our professor actually gave us the createAFunction assignment. I understand html but am having a little tough time with php. But thank you. I will see what i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. It will work!!!

### register.php:

```
echo '<form action="result.php" />';
echo '<div style="width:520px;height:175px;border:3px solid black;">';
createTextField('Name', 'label', 'size', '');
createTextField('Age', 'label', 'size = 5', '');
createTextField('Address', 'label', 'size = 30', '1000 1st St. Seattle, Wa 98999');
createTextField('Address (cont)', 'label', 'size = 10', 'APT 13');

echo '</div><br>';

//create TextArea
echo '<div style="width:520px;height:175px;border:3px solid black;">';
createTextArea('Short biography', 'label', 'cols', 'rows', 'defaultValue');
createTextArea('Extra Notes', 'label', 'cols', 'rows', 'defaultValue');
echo '</div><br>';

//create RadioButtons
echo '<div style="width:520px;height:75px;border:3px solid black;">';
createRadioButtons('Gender', 'name', 'Male', 'Female', 'Other');
createRadioButtons('Employment', 'name', 'Employed', 'Not Employed', 'Not sure');
echo '</div><br>';

//create DropDown
echo '<div style="width:520px;height:50px;border:3px solid black;">';
createDropDown('Did you like this questionnaire?', 'name', 'Yes', 'Sort Of', 'Maybe', 'No');
echo '</div><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />';
echo "</form>";
```

### result.php:

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  echo "Name: $name<br>";
} else {
  echo 'Name field cannot be empty!<br>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['address'])) {
  $name = $_POST['address'];
  echo "Address: $address<br>";
} else {
  echo 'Address field cannot be empty!<br>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
  $name = $_POST['text'];
  echo "Short Biography: $notes<br>";
} else {
  echo 'Notes field cannot be empty!<br>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['radio'])) {
  $name = $_POST['radio'];
  echo "Gender: $radio<br>";
} else {
  echo '';
}
```